# Form with jQuery don't working correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying make a form. Where when you select an option, the empty value is removed and the color changes.

But, when you change the option, all empty values are being removed at the same time.

What i have to do to resolve this?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Cjdbx/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.changeMe').change(function(){
      $('.empty').remove();
      $(this).css({'color':'black'});
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Cjdbx/4/

```
$('.changeMe').change(function(){
    $('.empty',this).remove();
    $(this).css({'color':'black'});
});
```

You are removing all classes with `empty`. You have to only remove the one which is related. So, use `this`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(this).find('.empty').remove();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Cjdbx/3/)

Comment: Agreed, this is the solution. Beat me to it by 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

OK, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.changeMe').change(function(){
          var $this = $(this);
          $this.parents("div").find('.empty').remove();
          $this.removeClass("blue");
          $this.addClass("black");
        });
    });
```

Basically, you need first to find the parent div (containing the row) and remove any .empty descendants.